# SQL Server 2012 Update Specific Column in CSV string

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

I am looking for some help coding something. We are trying to update a specific "column" of the CSV string that I have.

Here's a screenshot to illustrate my point:
[image: CSV Record]

The column "DataRow" has a CSV string that I need to modify. It's easy to locate the first column using CHARINDEX, but I can't seem code to go beyond that. I am trying to update the 3rd value in the string, in case of the first record, would be 'TM - Desert Wind Villas..'.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks much in advance!

Comment: Question 1. Why are you storing your data this way? Why not store all of that CSV information in different columns?

Comment: Hi Zane, Thanks for replying. It's a pre-populated table that we are trying to update. We do not have control on the way the data is stored.

Comment: There are methods at [http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html) to split the csv string. I suggest using a CLR procedure so that you can split the string (String.Split), edit the third array element, and join the array elements back together (String.Join).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I give you the code, I want to say that **change this design if you can!**

A database is meant to have tables and columns.  Using a delimited string violates normal form.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Thus, I makes it a-lot harder to manipulating data (D.M.L. ~ UPD, DEL, INS).

With that **CAUTION** out of the way, I solved your problem using the following algorithm.

```
1 - Create and load sample table with data.
2 - Choose a string split function, see article from Aaron Bertrand on choices.
3 - Split the string and store Items by Key, Column number order in a staging table 1
4 - Update the staging table 1.  I did it for all column 2's.  
    However, there could be a where clause to do partial updates.  
    Also you could use update_flag to identify changed rows.
5 - Repackage the items as a string.  I saved this step in staging table 2.
    Can leverage update_flag to only packaged changed rows from staging table 1.
6 - Update the original table with new strings.
```

Here is the sample code for this exercise.

```
-- Just playing
use tempdb;

-- Drop the sample table 
if OBJECT_ID('my_data') > 0
drop table my_data
go 

-- Drop stage table 1
if OBJECT_ID('stage1') > 0
drop table stage1
go 

-- Drop stage table 2
if OBJECT_ID('stage2') > 0
drop table stage2
go 

-- Create sample table
create table my_data 
(data_id INT, data_delimited_txt VARCHAR(100));

-- Add data
insert into my_data
values (1, '1,ABC,HZY'),(2, '2,DEF,XYZ'),(3, '3,ABC,MNP');

-- Show the data
select * from my_data;
go

-- http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

-- String split function, save 2 stage1
select 
  d.data_id, 
  row_number() over (partition by d.data_id order by (select 0)) as row_id, 
  s.item 
into
  stage1
from 
  my_data d cross apply 
  msdb.dbo.SplitStrings_XML(d.data_delimited_txt, ',') as s
GO

-- Update second (col/val) in string
update stage1 
set item = 'NEW VALUE'
where row_id = 2
go

-- Get updated string in stage2
select 
  data_id, 
  stuff(
  (
    SELECT ', ' + ISNULL(inner1.item,'') 
    FROM #stage as inner1
    WHERE inner1.data_id = outer1.data_id
    FOR XML PATH('')
  ) , 1, 2, '') as list_txt
into stage2
from stage1 as outer1
group by data_id
go

-- Update original table
update my_data
set data_delimited_txt = list_txt
from my_data m join stage2 s on m.data_id = s.data_id
go

-- Show the data
select * from my_data;
go
```

I leave enhancements like an update flag (upd_flag) and any step elimination for you to do.

Also, the XML split function depends on valid XML data.  A production release of this code should use another split function if that is a concern.

Good luck.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That code works exactly as needed! I agree with you on the much needed design change, but this is out of our scope; since it's an internal table used by an ERP system. They use this table to import CSV files and manipulate them with their internal stored procedures. We wanted to update the values in this table before the process moves on to the next steps. Again, this is extremely valuable information you've provided, it will no doubt save us a lot of time. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use where clause something as following I am only SELECT(ing) data but obviously you can use Update statement to Update the returned data. ...

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID INT, Data VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @T 
VALUES (1, '1,ABC,HZY'),(2, '2,DEF,XYZ'),(3, '3,ABC,MNP')

SELECT * FROM @T

╔════╦════════════╗
║ ID ║    Data    ║
╠════╬════════════╣
║  1 ║ 1,ABC,HZY  ║
║  2 ║ 2,DEF,XYZ  ║
║  3 ║ 3,ABC,MNP  ║
╚════╩════════════╝
```

**Query**

```
SELECT *
FROM @T
WHERE (',' + Data + ',') LIKE '%MNP%'

╔════╦════════════╗
║ ID ║    Data    ║
╠════╬════════════╣
║  3 ║ 3,ABC,MNP  ║
╚════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: Hi @M.Ali, Thank you so much for that code. From what I understand, in order to update this way, we would have to know the pattern or the characters in the string that needs to be updated, is that correct? In that case, we would run into an issue since we won't know each time we need to update what the string is going to be. All we are sure of is the position of the "column" in the CSV string; hope that makes more sense? Once again, thank you so much for taking your time out to help me with this. I appreciate it.